# Keyboard will freeze onscreen if active textfield changes while keyboard is up

Tags: objective-c, uikit

I have arrived at a situation where I can make the onscreen keyboard "stick" and even pressing the Close button on the keyboard has no effect.

The keyboard pops up when a `UITextField` is touched. Normal. But if a different `UITextField` is touched while the keyboard is up, and that textfield issues a `UIAlertView` (to notify user that editing is not available for that particular record), this alert view seems to somehow "lock" the keyboard. I tried to `resignFirstResponder` before the alert view is created or shown, but this has no effect. I'm using `- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` to determine whether editing is allowed or not, and this is method contains the code to show the alert view and resign first responder.

Has anyone had this experience or have a suggestion?

Comment: resignFirstResponder didnt have any effect because you did it in the event handler.  You need to do the resign then call back to your method that shows the alertView with performSelector:...afterDelay... since alertView will lock up the runloop and the resign will not get a chance to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` instead of the method mentioned in the question. Tested and resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When You Show Alert View Then for  Return No; for specific textfield. Because Alert View and KeyBoard Show at Once. Try to manage them according to your requirements.

Comment: why are you capitalizing every word in your sentences? it is hard to read

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[yourtextFieldObj endEditing:YES];
```

before showing the alert.. This may helps..